# Geocoder: if response is over query limit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-geocoder

How can I ask a [Geocoder](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder) gem address if the API query limit has been reached?

```
csv.each_with_index do |row, i|
  if !row[:location_1].nil?
    coords = row[:location_1]
    g = Geocoder.address(coords)
    row[:address] = g
  end

  if g.include?('over query limit')
    p "limit hit"
  end
end
```

I'm not sure which object to ask. The error comes through in the console:

```
Google Geocoding API error: over query limit.
```

But I'm not sure how to check for that in code. Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want to wrap your `Geocoder.address` in a begin/rescue block:

```
csv.each_with_index do |row, i|
  if !row[:location_1].nil?
    coords = row[:location_1]
    begin
      g = Geocoder.address(coords)
      row[:address] = g
    rescue Geocoder::OverQueryLimitError
      p "limit hit"
    end
  end
end
```

Just a note, you'll probably want to break out of the loop in the rescue clause once you hit this so you don't spam the geocoding web service with bad requests.

See [Geocoder errors](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder#error-handling).

Comment: You also need to tell `Geocoder` to raise that error. "By default Geocoder will rescue any exceptions raised by calls to a geocoding service and return an empty array." `Geocoder.configure(:always_raise => [Geocoder::OverQueryLimitError])`.